# 'package does not exist' using javac to convert .java class with google play services imports

Tags: java, google-play-services, javac, .class-file

I have a .java class which uses imports from google play services. I want to put this class in a .jar to package with my project, but using `javac filename.java` in the terminal gives me a bunch of errors e.g.

`androidSCAR.java:3: error: package android.content does not exist import android.content.Context;`

How do I include these imports while creating a .class?

The .java file is in an android studio project which all works fine

minimal example code:

myClass.java file:

```
import android.content.Context;

public class myClass
{

private static Context context;

}
```

Run `javac myClass.java` in terminal

Results:

```
test.java:1: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Context;
                      ^
test.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
private static Context context;
               ^
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class myClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around - I built the android project using the .java class and grabbed the .class files from **app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes\module-name**, and used those to create my .jar file.